# How can we block the redirection to the home screen from the Azure ad logout screen?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, owin, openid

After the application Sign-out, the **back button click will redirect the user back to the home screen of the application**.
How can we block the redirection to the home screen from the Azure ad logout screen?

- Application : .NET MVC 5
- Framework : 4.6.1

Please find the Sign out function below:

```
public void SignOut()
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
          
            if (Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] != null)
            {
                var c = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
                c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(c);
            }
            if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNet.ApplicationCookie"] != null)
            {
                var c = new HttpCookie(".AspNet.ApplicationCookie");
                c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(c);
            }

            if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies["__RequestVerificationToken"] != null)
            {
                var c = new HttpCookie("__RequestVerificationToken");
                c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                Response.Cookies.Add(c);
            }
            EndSession();
            Session.Abandon();
            AppSession.Clear();
        }


public void EndSession()
        {
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            this.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the PostLogoutRedirectURI in your appSettings  such that when you publish an application, the PostLogoutRedirectURI and the ReplyURL must match in order for the users to be authenticated. and add  the Logout URL `https://<baseurl>/signout-oidc`  field of the Advanced Settings section in the Authentication page in azure ad portal.

***ex:***

- In startup give postredirect url.

startup.cs

```
 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44320/Home/About",
              ...
    }
```

•   Along with that  Try to explicitly  give in controller  to triggers the **[SignOut](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-6-SignOut) action**  which clears the session cookie from the browser,
•   and finally calls back the logout URL, which, by default, displays the signed out view page

*code from  [AccountController -AzureAD. GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs)*:

```
[HttpGet("{scheme}")]
        public IActionResult SignOut(
            [FromRoute] string scheme)
        {
            if (AppServicesAuthenticationInformation.IsAppServicesAadAuthenticationEnabled)
            {
                return LocalRedirect(AppServicesAuthenticationInformation.LogoutUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                scheme ??= OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page("/Account/SignedOut", pageHandler: null, values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme);
                return SignOut(
                     new AuthenticationProperties
                     {
                         RedirectUri = callbackUrl,
                     },
                     CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                     scheme);
            }
        }
```

***Reference:***

[Reply URLs vs PostLogoutRedirectURIs in Azure Active Directory (AAD)
| by Marilee Turscak | Medium](https://marileeturscak.medium.com/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b)